# How to focus field when opening modal dialog

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, jsom

If I have a modal dialog which looks like the following, how can I focus the textarea after opening the dialog?

By simply adding `$('#txtArea').focus();` after the code, the `txtArea` has focus for only a moment.

[image]

```
var popupDiv = document.createElement('div');
popupDiv.innerHTML += '<textarea id="txtArea"></textarea><br/><br/>';
popupDiv.innerHTML += '<button onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK,  $(\'#txtArea\').val());">OK</button>';


SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
        html: popupDiv,
        title: '',
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true,
        autoSize: true,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: function () { ... }
}
```

Comment: are you doing this customization on sharepoint newform and editform??

Comment: It's on a listview webpart (regular view) via JSLink.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because it takes some time for the dialog to load and be added to the DOM, but the code flow does not wait for this to happen. As far as I know there is no event that is ran after the dialog is rendered, so I came up with the following solution.

```
setTimeout(function() {$('#txtArea').focus();}, 200);
```

The timeout waits for 1/5th a second, after which the Textarea is present in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you add the focus code like this:

```
popupDiv.innerHTML += '<script>$("#txtArea").focus();</script>';
```

As far is I know the content in the modal dialog is rendered as an iFrame, so you need to embed your code in the content of the iFrame. I'm not sure if you need te reference jQuery as well to make this work.

Comment: I tried to do this, I think the script is still ran before the area is added to the page.

Comment: And wrapping it in a $(document).ready(function () { $('#txtArea').focus() }); Does that help?